# convert string element to int from mongo array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My Mongo-DB document look as follows

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9b20b180c4a5698aa49281"), "arr" : [ 1, 2, 2, "23" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9b20b180c4a5698aa49282"), "arr" : [ 1, 2, 2, "23" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9b20b180c4a5698aa49283"), "arr" : [ 23, "234", 42, 24 
]}
```

i need to convert the single string element from "arr" array to int.

Comment: There is no way to convert without actually reading the documents in a loop and rewriting them, unless you actually can write to a completely new collection and use aggregate. If there's "billions" of documents, then they are probably on shards, so you could not do that anyway and could only write to a single "unsharded" collection

Comment: can you tell how can i do this with scanning whole docs NeilLunn

Comment: Does not matter if you have 1 or 1,000,00 elements to change. You loop the results and rewrite it. Still the same linked answer applies.

Comment: i dont know that much about mongo i just need the query to change these values @NeilLunn

Comment: That's what the link in the large box above your question is for.